# Hide Elements based on role

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm working with react and Firebase, and I made an app for Kindergarten. Now, I have some components that shouldn't be visible for the parents. Is there a simple way to do this ? This is my first app ever, especially with Firebase and react.

I was thinking something like checking the role and then just a simple if else statement. I'm not sure if that's a good logic.

**UPDATE**

my user hook:

```
export function useAllUsers() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const usersCollected = [];
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          usersCollected.push({
            ...doc.data(),
            uid: doc.id,
          });
        });
        setUsers(usersCollected);
        console.log(usersCollected);
      });
  }, []);
  return users;
}
```

Calendar :

```
function DateAndTimePickers() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [ort, setOrt] = useState("");
  const [notiz, setNotiz] = useState("");
  const [hinweis, setHinweis] = useState("");
  const [eintragen, setEintragen] = useState([]);
  const [dateandtime, setDateandtime] = useState([]);
 

  function handelDateandTime(e) {
    setDateandtime(e.target.value);
  }
  function handelOrt(e) {
    setOrt(e.target.value);
  }
  function handelNotiz(e) {
    setNotiz(e.target.value);
  }
  function handelHinweis(e) {
    setHinweis(e.target.value);
  }
  function KalenderEintrag() {
    db.collection("eintrag")
      .doc()
      .set({
        ort,
        notiz,
        hinweis,
        dateandtime,
      })
      .then(() => {

        setEintragen([...eintragen, { ort, notiz, hinweis, dateandtime }]);
        console.log("Documents saved succesfully");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  function fetchKalendareintrag() {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("eintrag")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        let loadedIfnos = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.data());
          return doc.data();
        });
        setEintragen(loadedIfnos);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchKalendareintrag();
  }, []);

  return (


//hide
        <ScrollView style={styles.root}>
          <Container>
            <TextField
              id="datetime-local"
              label="Neues Ereigniss"
              type="datetime-local"
              defaultValue="2021-09-16T10:30"
              className={classes.root}
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
              onChange={(value) => {
                handelDateandTime(value);
              }}
            />
      </Container>
      {/* ORT */}
      <Container className={classes.ortContainer}>
        <TextField
          id="standard-helperText"
          label="Ort"
          defaultValue="Text"
          onChange={(value) => {
            handelOrt(value);
          }}
        />
      </Container>
      {/* Hinweis */}
      <Container className={classes.ortContainer}>
        <TextField
          id="standard-helperText"
          label="Hinweis"
          defaultValue="Text"
          onChange={(value) => {
            handelHinweis(value);
          }}
        />
      </Container>
      {/* Notizen */}
      <Container className={classes.ortContainer}>
        <TextField
          id="standard-helperText"
          label="Notizen"
          defaultValue="Text"
          onChange={(value) => {
            handelNotiz(value);
          }}
        />
      </Container>
      

      <Container>
        <Button onClick={() => KalenderEintrag()}  className={classes.btn} variant="outlined">Absenden</Button>
      </Container>
//Show 
      {/* Kalender einträge  */}
      {/* Kalender einträge  */}
      {eintragen.map((item) => {
        return (
          <Card className={classes.card}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography
              className={classes.title}
              color="textSecondary"
              gutterBottom
            >
              {item.ort}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
              {item.hinweis}
            </Typography>
            <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
              {item.notiz}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
              {item.dateandtime}
              <br />
             
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions>
            
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
        )
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}



const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
  eintrag: store.userState.currentUser,
 
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(DateAndTimePickers);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple `if else` statement or `switch` block you can use to check for roles but as application starts growing it will be a tedious task to manage all the roles-based logic. It all deals with how you set up your architecture to handle the `role` based flow.

I've also encountered a similar flow.

What you can do is create hooks, like `useHasRoles` and `useUser`.

`useHasRoles` hook will check whether your current logged in user has specified role or not. And to get the current user details, we are having another hook as `useUser` which will return the current user details and roles of that specific user.

**useHasRoles (hook)**

```
const useHasRoles =(roleNames)=>{
const roles =  useUser();

if (typeof roleNames === "string") {
  //check whether current user has specific role or not
  //return true/false
  } else if (Array.isArray(roleNames)) {
   //check if current user has all roles specified in roleNames
  //return true/false
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**useUser (hook)**

```
const useUser = ()=>{
   //get current user details and roles.
   return {roles:[]}
}
```

**How to use?**

```
const sample = ()=>{
    const hasAdminRole = useHasRoles('ADMIN') // ['ADMIN', 'SUPERADMIN']
    // you can pass roles as array, so it will check for all the roles.
}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I already have a User hook if I would like to use the roles I would need to just change it a little or?

Comment: You can change your user hook such that it should have all the roles of that currently accessing user. And later in `useHasRoles` hook you can check the passed roles with the  roles of current user

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this.

Here is a simple TextButton which is disabled if the user is a parent:

```js
interface Props {
  onPress: () => void
  children: string
  userRole: UserRole
}

const TextButton = ({ onPress, children, userRole }: Props) => {
  const disabled = userRole === UserRole.Parent

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={1}
      style={styles.button}
      onPress={onPress}
      disabled={disabled}>
      <Text
        style={styles.text}
        {children}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

Here I use a modal with elements conditionally rendered.

```
<Modal {...{ isVisible, onClose, hasBackdrop, displayName: Alert.displayName }}>
      <View style={[styles.container, getType(), { paddingBottom }]}>
        {isCloseIcon && (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.closeContainer} onPress={onClose}>
            <SvgView testID={alertCloseIcon} svg={<IconClose style={styles.closeIcon} />} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <SvgView style={styles.closeIconContainer} svg={icon} />
          <Text testID={alertTitle} style={getTextStyles()}>
            {title}
          </Text>
          {!!subtitle && (
            <Text testID={alertSubtitle} style={styles.subtitle}>
              {subtitle}
            </Text>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
```

Comment: @DavidShimonBaars I updated the post because I also like your solution, but I would like to know how would you implement this ? I tried something like this before and all I got was errors haha so I'm doing something wrong. There are comments with part I would like to hide and with to show on the Calendar.js. :)

Comment: What errors were you getting?
I added another example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way to do it :D
I already had a User hook, so there were no need for me to do anything extra because I'm checking the role in my user collection. All I had to do was to check the role. Maybe that's not the vest explanation, but English is not my native language and that's the best I can do :').
If someone is having the same trouble, I hope this helps!
And thanks @DovidShimonBaars and @ShubhamJajoo

```
{user?.role === "parent" && (
        <>
          <Container>
            <TextField
              id="datetime-local"
              label="Neues Ereigniss"
              type="datetime-local"
              defaultValue="2021-09-16T10:30"
              className={classes.root}
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
              onChange={(value) => {
                handelDateandTime(value);
              }}
            />
          </Container>
          {/* ORT */}
          <Container className={classes.ortContainer}>
            <TextField
              id="standard-helperText"
              label="Ort"
              defaultValue="Text"
              onChange={(value) => {
                handelOrt(value);
              }}
            />
          </Container>
          {/* Hinweis */}
          <Container className={classes.ortContainer}>
            <TextField
              id="standard-helperText"
              label="Hinweis"
              defaultValue="Text"
              onChange={(value) => {
                handelHinweis(value);
              }}
            />
          </Container>
          {/* Notizen */}
          <Container className={classes.ortContainer}>
            <TextField
              id="standard-helperText"
              label="Notizen"
              defaultValue="Text"
              onChange={(value) => {
                handelNotiz(value);
              }}
            />
          </Container>
       
    

      <Container>
        <Button
          onClick={() => KalenderEintrag()}
          className={classes.btn}
          variant="outlined"
        >
          Absenden
        </Button>
      </Container>
      </>  )}
```